# Perfect way to delete a simple std map of ints and strings

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

My std::map looks like this.

```
std::map<int, std::string> *myMap = new std::map<int, std::string>[100];
```

How do I delete this? Is `delete myMap` enough?

Comment: Can you say a little bit about why the problem you are trying to solve calls for the allocation of a `std::map` array?

Comment: How about `std::vector<std::map<int, std::string>> myMaps(100);`? Then you don't need to worry about deleting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have allocated 100 `std::map`s with `new[]`, you must deallocate them with `delete[]`:

```
delete[] myMap;
```

For every `new`/`new[]`, there must be a `delete`/`delete[]` (respectively).

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of maps, so you're almost correct. You need to `delete [] myMap` to clean up the array properly.

But don't do that. Use a `vector` of maps instead:

```
std::vector<std::map<int, std::string> > myMap(100);
```

This will take care of all the memory management and cleanup for you automatically!

Answer (score 0):

boost::scoped_ptr< std::map > myMap = new std::map[100];

It is highly recommended to use boost::scoped_ptr and boost::shared_ptr (when a memory location is being accessed by more than one thigns) which are smart pointers and come with many advantages. They support custom deleter so they are memory safe, which means you do not have to worry about deleting things you created using new or new[]. They are also thread safe. Their implementation is templated and they work with any type etc.

Comment: If you're using Boost, you'll need `scoped_array`, not `scoped_ptr`, and you'll need direct- rather than copy-initialisation. In modern C++, `std::unique_ptr<map_type[]>` (or `std::vector`) would be preferable.